# Python3 how do i serialize a class variable in a class using __slots__

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, multiprocessing

I have a class which is a support interface used between Threads.

Because of its nature I had to make a custom **__getstate__** and **__setstate__**. The class have a UniqueCounter to help create unique id's for the said interface. However  the class also uses **__slots__** to limit the overhead (Many can be created of said class)

The Class looks as following:

```
class WriterIf(object):

  UniqueCounter = 0

  __slots__ = [
    '_UpdateQueue',
    'WriterIfId',
    '_weakWriterPtr',
    '_MasterIf',
    '_TestName',
    '_TestCaseName',
    '_GroupeName',
    '_TestStatus',
    '_Serialized',
  ]

  def __init__(self, WriterMQ, MasterIf : bool = False):
    self._UpdateQueue         = WriterMQ
    self.WriterIfId           = self.UniqueCounter

    self._GroupeName          = None
    self._TestCaseName        = None
    self._TestName            = None
    self._TestStatus          = self.T_STATUS_NA
    self._Serialized          = False


    type(self).UniqueCounter += 1

    if MasterIf:
      self.WriterIfId = -1

    self._MasterIf = MasterIf


  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def __getstate__(self):
    self.RmQueue()
    self._Serialized = True
    returnValue = {slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__ if hasattr(self, slot)}
    return returnValue

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def __setstate__(self, stat):
    for slot, value in stat.items():
      setattr(self, slot, value)
```

This works as it should, serializing my slots and restoring my **__slots__ values. However my UniqueCounter do not get updated which makes sense since its not part of **__slots__**. (I am acturaly not sure if my UniqueCounter breaks the advantage of **__slots__**).

Now I tried to pack that variable into my **returnValue** in the **__getstate__** method. However if I try to set it directly at the **__setstate__** I get a **'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment** error. 
I cannot add it using setattr either because the attribute is read-only.

Any ideas?. Should I stop using slots (I have not tried yet if that works) but I would like to stick with **__slots__ if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the two Methods **__getstate__** and **__setstate__** like below

```
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def __getstate__(self):
    self.RmQueue()
    self._Serialized = True
    returnValue = {slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__ if hasattr(self, slot)}
    returnValue['ClassVariables'] = {'UniqueCounter': type(self).UniqueCounter}
    return returnValue

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def __setstate__(self, stat):
    for slot, value in stat.items():
      if slot == 'ClassVariables':
        for ClassVariableName, ClassValue in value.items():
          if ClassVariableName == 'UniqueCounter':
            self.SetUniqueCounter(ClassValue)
      else:
        setattr(self, slot, value)
```

and add the method

```
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def SetUniqueCounter(self, val):
    type(self).UniqueCounter = val
```

I do not get the error **'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment** and can now set my UniqueCounter.

However I do not understand why this is legal and direct assignment is not. If anyone could clear that up for me I would be glad. However the above works and I get my Class Variable set after serialization.